# mostrar en un pdf solo lo que se muestre en una tabla

Tags: php, html

Quisiera saber si es posible mostrar en un `pdf` lo que se encuentra en una página de una tabla y cómo realizarlo. Por ejemplo: Si tengo 100 datos y tengo una paginación que me muestre de 10 en 10 y selecciono la página 3  me estaría mostrando del 21 al 30; al mostrar el `pdf` quiero que únicamente me muestre los datos que estén en esa página.

[image: imagen_de_muestra]

Si cambio de página mostrar en un `pdf` los datos de dicha página únicamente.

Comment: Hola amigo como estas puedes revisar este complemento
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script100.php pdf grid php

Comment: Como quieres exportar los elementos, Conservando los estilos CSS y estructura de tabla, de forma personalizada con cabecera y logo?, Esa paginación es javascript o la haces mediante PHP ? Prueba domPDF

Comment: en esa tabla la paginación la realizo con javascript, estoy usando fpdf pero lo estoy mostrando con una consulta sql que me bota todos los datos lo que me gustaría  es mostrar los datos que se muestran en esa paginación.

Answer (score 2):

Para exportar a pdf utilizo la librería dompdf, En tu caso tienes dos opciones, si la tabla tiene un javascript puedes averiguar si es posible obtener del dataSource con las filas actuales, con lo cual puedes enviar los datos en en una variable por GET o POST que la reciba el archivo export.php.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../phpModules/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
//en caso de venir en un directamente array un desde Javascript
  $table=$_GET['table'];

//en caso de que envies la informacion como JSON.Stringfy desde Javascript con esto obtienes los datos en un array
$table=json_decode($_GET['table'],true);
$paginaPDF="<html>
<head>
    <title>Mi reporte</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='cabecera'>
    aca puedes incluir el logo y todos los detalles de cabecera
    </div>
";

$htmlDeTabla='<table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Columna A</td><td>Columna B</td><td>Columna C</td>
        </tr>';
foreach($table as $data){
    $htmlDeTabla.'<tr>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaA'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaB'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaC'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$paginaPDF.=$htmlDeTabla.'</body></html>';

//Se codifica el PDF
$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('letter');//Tamaño de papel
$dompdf->render();
$base64 = base64_encode($dompdf->output());
//Mostrar el pdf en el navegador
echo '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . $base64 . '" ></iframe>';
```

Si no puedes obtener los datos de la vista actual, la otra opcion es el numero de pagina actual, Con lo cual tendrías que hacer los cálculos para los registros de la paginación y lanzar la consulta a la BD.

```
$paginaActual=$_GET['page_num'];//El numero de pagina actual del Grid
$itemsPorPagina=100; //
$desde=(int)$paginaActual*$itemsPorPagina;
$query='select * from my table LIMIT '.$itemsPorPagina.' OFFSET '.$desde;
$result=MyDabase->Executequery($query); //Cualquier metodo que ejecute la consulta

$htmlDeTabla='<table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Columna A</td><td>Columna B</td><td>Columna C</td>
        </tr>';
foreach($result as $data){
    $htmlDeTabla.'<tr>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaA'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaB'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ColumnaC'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
// Lo demas igual al anterior
```

El problema en sí, no está en exportar a pdf, si no en que puedas conocer estos dos datos, de acuerdo a alguna función del Grid